# Динамическое добавление виджетов

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, qlistwidget

Имеется форма, которая должна динамически добавлять набор новых виджетов и в последующем данные в этих виджетов будут записаны в `json`.

По дефолту имеется одна запись категорий с различными типами виджетов:

[image: пример 1]

По нажатию на кнопку добавить аналогичный список виджетов появляется ниже предыдущего и в последующем нужно получить такой вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я правильно понял нужно реализовать динамическое добавление виджетов, но я не могу прийти к правильной мысли на данный момент.

Пример кода

```
class UiCategoryWindow(object):
_translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

def setup_ui(self, form):
    form.setObjectName("form")
    form.resize(520, 250)
    form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(520, 250))
    form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(520, 1000))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    form.setFont(font)
    
    self.grid_layout_in_form = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(form)
    self.grid_layout_in_form.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
    self.grid_layout_in_form.setObjectName("grid_layout_in_form")
    
    self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(form)
    self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll_area.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.scroll_area.setObjectName("scroll_area")
    
    self.scroll_area_widget_contents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scroll_area_widget_contents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 494, 156))
    self.scroll_area_widget_contents.setObjectName("scroll_area_widget_contents")
    
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.setObjectName("grid_layout_in_scroll_area")
    
    self.line_edit_number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_number.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))
    self.line_edit_number.setText("")
    self.line_edit_number.setObjectName("line_edit_number")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_number, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.line_edit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_name.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 20))
    self.line_edit_name.setText("")
    self.line_edit_name.setObjectName("line_edit_name")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    self.line_edit_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_path.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
    self.line_edit_path.setObjectName("line_edit_path")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_path, 0, 2, 1, 1)

    self.label_for_photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.label_for_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 24))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.label_for_photo.setFont(font)
    self.label_for_photo.setText("")
    self.label_for_photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../Downloads/data/categories/8.jpeg"))
    self.label_for_photo.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label_for_photo.setObjectName("label_for_photo")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.label_for_photo, 0, 3, 1, 1)

    self.push_button_add_photo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(58, 25))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setObjectName("push_button_add_photo")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.push_button_add_photo, 0, 4, 1, 1)

    self.push_button_remove_category = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 25))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../MainTable/images/icon/remote.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setIcon(icon)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setObjectName("push_button_remove_category")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.push_button_remove_category, 0, 5, 1, 1)
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.grid_layout_in_form.addWidget(self.scroll_area, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    
    self.push_button_save_categories = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_save_categories.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_save_categories.setObjectName("push_button_save_categories")
    self.grid_layout_in_form.addWidget(self.push_button_save_categories, 4, 0, 1, 1)
    
    self.push_button_add_category = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_add_category.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_add_category.setObjectName("push_button_add_category")
    self.push_button_add_category.clicked.connect(form.add_new_category)
    self.grid_layout_in_form.addWidget(self.push_button_add_category, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.retranslate_Ui(form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(form)

def retranslate_Ui(self, form):
    form.setWindowTitle(self._translate("form", "Добавить категории"))
    self.line_edit_number.setPlaceholderText(self._translate("form", "№"))
    self.line_edit_name.setPlaceholderText(self._translate("form", "Введите имя категории"))
    self.push_button_save_categories.setText(self._translate("form", "Сохранить"))
    self.push_button_add_photo.setText(self._translate("form", "Фото"))
    self.push_button_add_category.setText(self._translate("form", "Добавить"))

def add_new_category(self):
    self.line_edit_number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_number.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))
    self.line_edit_number.setText("")
    self.line_edit_number.setObjectName("line_edit_number")
    self.line_edit_number.setPlaceholderText(self._translate("form", "№"))
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_number, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.line_edit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_name.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 20))
    self.line_edit_name.setText("")
    self.line_edit_name.setObjectName("line_edit_name")
    self.line_edit_name.setPlaceholderText(self._translate("form", "Введите имя категории"))
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    self.line_edit_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.line_edit_path.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
    self.line_edit_path.setObjectName("line_edit_path")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.line_edit_path, 0, 2, 1, 1)

    self.label_for_photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.label_for_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 24))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.label_for_photo.setFont(font)
    self.label_for_photo.setText("")
    self.label_for_photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/icon/category_plug.png"))
    self.label_for_photo.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label_for_photo.setObjectName("label_for_photo")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.label_for_photo, 0, 3, 1, 1)

    self.push_button_add_photo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(58, 25))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_add_photo.setObjectName("push_button_add_photo")
    self.push_button_add_photo.setText(self._translate("form", "Фото"))
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.push_button_add_photo, 0, 4, 1, 1)

    self.push_button_remove_category = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 25))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setFont(font)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/icon/remote.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setIcon(icon)
    self.push_button_remove_category.setObjectName("push_button_remove_category")
    self.grid_layout_in_scroll_area.addWidget(self.push_button_remove_category, 0, 5, 1, 1)
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_area_widget_contents)
    self.grid_layout_in_form.addWidget(self.scroll_area, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов, того что вы хотите сделать, выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

        
class ItemWidget(QWidget):
    itemDeleted = pyqtSignal(QListWidgetItem)

    def __init__(self, text, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self._item = item                 # Сохраните ссылку на объект элемента списка

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        
        self.line_edit_number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit() 
        self.line_edit_number.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))
        self.line_edit_number.setPlaceholderText("№")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_number, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.line_edit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit() 
        self.line_edit_name.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 20))
        self.line_edit_name.setPlaceholderText("Введите имя категории")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.line_edit_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(text) 
        self.line_edit_path.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_path, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.label_for_photo = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.label_for_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 24))
        self.label_for_photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.label_for_photo.setScaledContents(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_for_photo, 0, 3, 1, 1)

        self.push_button_add_photo = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Фото")
        self.push_button_add_photo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(58, 25))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push_button_add_photo, 0, 4, 1, 1)

        self.push_button_remove_category = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self, clicked=self.doDeleteItem)
        self.push_button_remove_category.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 25))
        self.push_button_remove_category.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/close.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.push_button_remove_category.setIcon(icon)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.push_button_remove_category, 0, 5, 1, 1)
       
    def doDeleteItem(self):
        self.itemDeleted.emit(self._item)
        
        
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = 1

        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)

        self.addBtn = QPushButton('Добавить', self, clicked=self.doAdd)
        self.saveBtn = QPushButton("Сохранить")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)  
        layout.addWidget(self.addBtn)        
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)        
        layout.addWidget(self.saveBtn)

        # Добавить данные
        self.testData()

    def doDeleteItem(self, item):
        # Получить количество строк, соответствующих item
        row = self.listWidget.indexFromItem(item).row()
        # Удалить item
        item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
        # Удалить widget
        self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
        del item

    def doAdd(self):
        self.testData()

    def testData(self):
        # Создать данные
        item = QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        item.setSizeHint(QSize(520, 60)) 
                    
        widget = ItemWidget(f'{self.num}', item, self.listWidget)
        # Сигнал удаления привязки
        widget.itemDeleted.connect(self.doDeleteItem)
        self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)
        self.num += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 14, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Window()
    w.resize(550, 350)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]